# Method Overriding C++

Tags: c++, overriding

I got a Question in my Exam which was this:

> Function Overriding means the functions have the same prototype but
>   differ in their body
>
> Justify the Statement with the help of an Example.

Now I quoted this code snippet as Example :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std; 
class A {
    public: virtual void print() {
        cout << "I am Base Class's print Function" << endl;
    }
};

class B: public A {
    public: void print() {
        cout << "I am Derived's Class print function" << endl;
    }
};
```

Here I have made two classes, Class A and Class B and Class B is inheriting Class A. Now, by definition of Method Overriding, we mean that the Function which gets created in the Base Class gets overridden in the Derived Class. 
I made the Function in the Base Class as a Virtual Function.

Now, my `main()` file:

```
int main() {
    A * a1;
    B b1;
    a1 = & b1;
    a1 - > print();
}
```

Now, I want to ask that is my above code snippet example for above question is right or not. I have performed Function Overriding at run time. In my main file, the Base Class Object is a Pointer that is having the Address of the Derived Class. When I will call `print()` function using `a1`, it will execute the `print()` function of the Derived Class.

So isn't my example justified? Am I right or not?

Comment: only your teacher/prof can know what they consider as valid answer. That being said, I would expect a complete example to use the `override` specifier and to demonstrate how a method in a derived with same name but different prototype does actually not override a method in the base

Comment: also note that `A` should have a virtual destructor

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 My prof said that , we have to state the example for Compile Time , not Run Time , but even if i state the example run-time won't it be marked as Valid ?

Comment: sorry I dont understand what that last comment means. virtual dispatch happens at runtime, what does it mean to "state the example for Compile Time" ?

Comment: If I had posed this question, and you have provided that code as the answer, I'd give it full credit for answering the question.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Prof said that you have to do it without the use of virtual function in the Base Class

Comment: @Eljay So Sir , Am i Right na ?

Comment: sorry, but "do it without the use of virtual function in the Base Class" doesnt make much sense for overriding methods.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 So am i right in my approach of using virtual functions for demonstrating the example for Method Overriding ?

Comment: I already told you, I am missing `override` in your example and I would add a negative example of method with same name but different prototype in the derived. I would give a 8/10 perhaps (partly for the missing virtual destructor which is essential), but if you disagree with your teacher you have to ask them, we cannot know why they rated your solution the way they did

Comment: If the person asking the question was looking for function hiding kind of function overriding, it'd be like this (without `virtual`): https://beginnersbook.com/2017/09/cpp-function-overriding/

Comment: @Eljay My Prof was exactly demanding the same example as mentioned in the Website , but what is the difference if i have done it using the Pointer Approach using Virtual Function ?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 https://beginnersbook.com/2017/09/cpp-function-overriding/ This Websitev

Comment: your example is about overriding virtual methods, the one on the website not. Now it really just depends on what your teacher expected as answer

Comment: strictly speaking you cannot "override" a non-virtual method, not sure but perhaps "hiding" is the more correct term

Answer (score 0):

You could use the classical Cat vs Dog example where both classes inherit from a common base class, i.e. Animal. The common base class can then have a pure virtual function that is then overridden with a differing implementation (method body) in each subclass.

```
#include <iostream>

class Animal
{
public:
    virtual ~Animal() = default;
    virtual void MakeSound() const = 0;
};

class Dog : public Animal
{
public:
    virtual void MakeSound() const override;
};

class Cat : public Animal
{
public:
    virtual void MakeSound() const override;
};

void Dog::MakeSound() const
{
    std::cout << "Woof!" << std::endl;
}

void Cat::MakeSound() const
{
    std::cout << "Meow!" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    const Dog dog{};
    const Cat cat{};    
    const Animal& firstAnimal{dog};
    const Animal& secondAnimal{cat};

    /*
     * These functions have the same prototype, void MakeSound(),
     * but differ in their implementation.
     */
    firstAnimal.MakeSound();
    secondAnimal.MakeSound();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what does this add that isnt present in OPs code? Please explain

Comment: Not much, it is basically just a more structured way of answering the question from the exam. I would have expected OP to at least instatiate one instance of the `A` class and call `print()` on it. It all depends on whether OP wants to highlight static vs dynamic binding.

Answer (score 0):

If you teacher expected [this](https://beginnersbook.com/2017/09/cpp-function-overriding/) as answer and considers your example as wrong then I would argue that they teach you overriding the wrong way.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual):

> Virtual functions are member functions whose behavior can be overridden in derived classes.

Of course this does not strictly imply the reverse statement: "functions that can be overriden are virtual". But if this wasnt true, the quoted sentence would make little sense.

Non-virtual methods are not really meant to be overriden. From the [C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance#redefining-nonvirtuals):

> **Should a derived class redefine (“override”) a member function that is non-virtual in a base class?**
>
> It’s legal, but it ain’t moral. [...]

Note that they put "override" in quotes, because strictly speaking it is not overriding but merely redefining.

Further, you can read on [cpprefernce](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) about the `override` specifier (emphasize mine):

> In a member function declaration or definition, **override ensures that the function is virtual** and is overriding a virtual function from a base class. The program is ill-formed (a compile-time error is generated) if this is not true.

**TL;DR** If I had to judge I would consider [this](https://beginnersbook.com/2017/09/cpp-function-overriding/) as a misleading bad example for overriding, while your code seems fine. It could benefit from using `override` and `A` should have a virtual destructor, but thats details.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Sir !!