# error: 'class Parent' has no member named 'count'

Tags: c++, arduino

unfortunately I am not very familiar with c ++ but I need it for an Arduino project. I very much hope someone can help me in an uncomplicated way. In other programming languages ​​such as PHP, the code would work.

Here is a simplified example of my problem. I need a function (in the case "`void x(Parent& o)`") which takes as an argument all classes that descend from a certain parent class (in the case "`class Parent`").

```
class Parent {
  public:
    int c = 0;
    String name;

  Parent(String n) {
    name = n;
    }

  String getName() {
    return name;
    }

  int getCounter() {
    return c;
    }
  };

class Child_foo: public Parent {
  public:
    Child_foo(String n): Parent(n) {
      }

    void count() {
      c++;
      }
  };

class Child_bar: public Parent {
  public:
    Child_bar(String n): Parent(n) {
      }

    void count() {
      c--;
      }
  };

Child_foo foo("foo");
Child_bar bar("bar");

void x(Parent& o) {
   Serial.println(o.getName());
   o.count();
   Serial.println(o.getCounter());
  }

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  }

void loop() {
  x(foo);
  x(bar);
  delay(750);
  }
```

```
sketch_jun18a.ino: In function 'void x(Parent&)':
sketch_jun18a:44:6: error: 'class Parent' has no member named 'count'
    o.count();
      ^
exit status 1
'class Parent' has no member named 'count'
```

If I use "`void x(Child_foo& o)`" or "`void x(Child_bar& o)`" instead of "`void x(Parent& o)`" then the code works. However, there are different child classes with different methods that should be used in the "`void x(Parent& o)`" function.

So how can I tell the function "`void x(Parent& o)`" to accept all child classes and that I can access their methods? (The method "`void count()`" is only an example. Completely different methods can exist in different child classes.)

Comment: This is the way C++ works. If you have a Parent pointer or reference you can access methods and member variables that Parent has, even if the instance passed is a child type with more methods and member variables. The normal way to handle this would be to make a virtual function in the base class and then override it in the children. If there is no appropriate behavior you can make the function pure virtual which requires the child to override it or the child class cannot be instantiated.

Comment: How do you plan to use different child classes with different methods in `x`, if you don't know what they are? All you know is that `o` is either a `Parent` or is derived from it.

Comment: In the original code, the function "x" is a lamda function that is controlled by other code. A child class is then always passed there. But I don't know which child class so I can only specify the parent class as the type.

At the point where I define the lamda function, of course I already know which child I am expecting with which methods.

Answer (score 1):

[Method Overriding C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59034206/method-overriding-c)

```
class Parent {
   virtual void count() = 0; // <-- Adding this line could solve this problem
}
```